# SQL Server - Set FileTable Directory to "C:\Example"

Tags: sql-server, directory, filetable

How do I set a `FileTable_Directory` to a custom path such as `C:\Example`? Can I change this directory on demand and will it reflect the changes upon update in the database? Here's my FileTable setup:

```
-- Enable Filestream
EXEC sp_configure filestream_access_level, 2
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- Create Database
CREATE DATABASE FileTableDB
ON PRIMARY
(Name = FileTableDB,
FILENAME = 'C:\FileTable\FTDB.mdf'),
FILEGROUP FTFG CONTAINS FILESTREAM
(NAME = FileTableFS,
FILENAME='C:\FileTable\FS')
LOG ON
(Name = FileTableDBLog,
FILENAME = 'C:\FileTable\FTDBLog.ldf')
WITH FILESTREAM (NON_TRANSACTED_ACCESS = FULL,
DIRECTORY_NAME = N'FileTableDB');
GO

USE FileTableDB
GO
CREATE TABLE FileTableTb AS FileTable
WITH
(FileTable_Directory = 'FileTableTb_Dir');
GO
```

Comment: Why not `FILENAME = 'C:\FileTable\FileTableDB.mdf'` AND `FILENAME = 'C:\FileTable\FileTableDBLog.ldf'` instead?

Comment: @Sami That's not setting the directory. That is setting up the database file location.